# Libgdx: SetScreen Issues

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hello the following code is from my main class trying to call another class i made which implements screen.

```
if (grumpface.whiteballoon.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(spriterect)) {

        System.out.println("hey");
            setScreen(new GameOverScreen());
        }
        ;
```

here is the class i am calling.

```
class GameOverScreen implements Screen{

    private Stage stage;


    // Called automatically once for init objects
    @Override
    public void show() { 




       stage = new Stage();
        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
       stage.setDebugAll(true); // Set outlines for Stage elements for easy debug

        BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("hazey.fnt"), false);
        LabelStyle headingStyle = new LabelStyle(white, Color.WHITE);
        Label gameoverstring = new Label("game ovaaaa!", headingStyle);
        gameoverstring.setPosition(100, 100);
        stage.addActor(gameoverstring);




    }

    // Called every frame so try to put no object creation in it
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) { 
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        System.out.println("hey");


        stage.act(delta);

        stage.draw();



    }
```

even though i am not returning any stack errors, my program still will not switch screen whenever the event is performed. i can tell the gameoverscreen class is getting called, because whenever the event happens the `System.out.println("hey");` is triggered and starts in the console. however, there is no color clear or label drawing like there should be.

Comment: have a look at the example syntax provided by BadLogicGames: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses as i don't know the context of your code, you'll need to find the syntax errors yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Show() like that. You should initialize your objects in your constructor. maybe try to set screen like that :

```
((com.badlogic.gdx.Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
            .setScreen(new GameScreen());
```

We need to see more code to help you

ps i can't comment, but the link : https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses is outdated, check it : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki